# How to add a user without /home?

Tags: users, home-directory

I want to create a new user to run a service on the system but don't want to have `/home` and other configuration files for it. Like there is a user for postgres but it doesn't have any `/home` directory.

Comment: I just found this http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/add-a-user-on-ubuntu-server/

Answer (score 153, accepted):

By default the command useradd doesn't create home directories, but for a daemon I recommend you to use the system option and change the shell to a non-existent one so no one can login with said account (in ssh for example):

```
sudo useradd -r -s /bin/false USERNAME
```

You can see all the options with `man useradd` and `man groupadd` if you want to create a group for the user too.

Comment: useradd -r creates a system user, not only a user with no homedir.

Comment: notice, useradd -r also creates corresponding groups.

Comment: I believe the best practice is using `/sbin/nologin` as the login shell, although, using `/bin/false` wouldn't make any differences.

Answer (score 65):

Try `adduser --system --no-create-home USERNAME` or simply have a look at the [`man adduser`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/man8/adduser.8.html) which claims to be a "*friendlier front end to the low level tools like useradd...*".

Comment: I actually didn't notice that this is `adduser` vs. `useradd`, and running the command `useradd` with these options did not produce any error, but created the account with shell `/bin/bash`.  "Buyer Beware".

Comment: in centos7, group is not created by defaulty.  ref: [root@srvr0 ava]# adduser --system --no-create-home --group bigdata
adduser: group 'bigdata' does not exist

Answer (score 21):

I needed something similar - a new user without login privileges and tied to a system service.  However, the answer by Clausi creates a user with the primary group as 'nogroup', which wasn't really desirable.

`adduser --system --no-create-home --group USERNAME` creates a system group with the same name as the user and associates it with the user as the primary group.  This can then be verified by using the `groups USERNAME` or the `id USERNAME` command.

Comment: in centos7, group is not created by defaulty.  ref: [root@srvr0 ava]# adduser --system --no-create-home --group bigdata
adduser: group 'bigdata' does not exist

Answer (score 6):

To add user without home directory the commands are,

```
useradd -M username
```

or

```
useradd --no-create-home username
```

or

```
adduser -M username
```

or

```
adduser --no-create-home username
```

Answer (score -1):

try this command:

`sudo useradd vivek`

This will create a user without creating your home folder at `/home/vivek`

Comment: No, as long as you are logged in with this account, the `/home/vivek` will be automatically created.

Answer (score -1):

Creating a User **without** Password **with** Home directory:

---

##### User & Group

*Create the desired Group and User with Home-Dir.*

```
mkdir <HOME-DIR>
sudo adduser --disabled-password --home <HOME-DIR> --group <GROUP-NAME>
sudo useradd -s /bin/bash -d <HOME-DIR> -g <GROUP-NAME> <USER-NAME>
```

##### Permissions

```
sudo chown <USER>:<USER> -R <HOME-DIR>    # Owner permissions
sudo chmod 775 -R <HOME-PATH>             # Optional
```

##### Add your primary user to the new group (Optional)

```
sudo usermod -a -G <GROUP-NAME> <PRIMARY-USER-NAME>
```

*To see all the groups, use: `$ id`, `$ groups`. login to a user: `$ sudo su - <USER>`. Re-login or Reset-PC is required.*

##### Remove User and Group

```
sudo deluser --remove-home <USER-NAME>
```