# Postgresql server installation keeps failing due to postgresql-common error

Tags: 12.04, software-installation, postgresql

The installation of postgresql server in Ubuntu 12.04 fails. 
Its seem to be due to incomplete configuration of postgresql-common package.
 I purged all packages related to postgresql, tried to reinstall postgresql-common package only. Still error was occuring.

The error is:

```
$ sudo apt-get install postgresql-common
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  postgresql-common
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/96.5 kB of archives.
After this operation, 442 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package postgresql-common.
(Reading database ... 176855 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking postgresql-common (from .../postgresql-common_129ubuntu1_all.deb) ...
Adding 'diversion of /usr/bin/pg_config to /usr/bin/pg_config.libpq-dev by postgresql-common'
Processing triggers for ureadahead ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Setting up postgresql-common (129ubuntu1) ...
adduser: The user `postgres' does not exist.
dpkg: error processing postgresql-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 postgresql-common
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Any idea how to overcome/solve this?

**N.B:**

1. I updated and tried again, same error is occuring.
2. I purged the postgresql related packages and tried to install both `postgresql-8.4` and `postgresql-9.1`, in both cases, it failed due to the dependency to `postgresql-common` package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that `postgres` user was not getting created.(Looks like an error with the package configuration scripts, not sure though) I then created the user manually using:

```
sudo useradd -r -s /bin/false postgres
```

The above command is to create a user, without home directory.([Courtesy](https://askubuntu.com/a/29364/11932))

After that I tried to install again, and it succeeded, without any problems.

**N.B:**
Some guys at the Ubuntu IRC channel helped me with the solution.

**Update:**

After restart `postgresql` server was not accessible, so tried to restart `postgresql` server, and got the following error:

```
$ sudo service postgresql restart
[sudo] password for username: 
 * Restarting PostgreSQL 8.4 database server                                     
 * The PostgreSQL server failed to start. Please check the log output:
2014-04-03 09:54:22 IST FATAL:  could not create lock file "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432.lock": Permission denied
[fail]
```

Solved it by editing the `postgresql.conf` file. We have to look for the line that begins with that begins `unix_socket_directory` and change it to read as the following:

```
unix_socket_directory='/tmp'
```

Now start the postgresql server using:

```
sudo service postgresql start
```

The problem was because

> the default directory for lock files in Ubuntu was changed to
>   /var/run/postgresql, which is not world-writable. However, simply
>   changing write permissions on the directory does not work; they are
>   reset when the default init script runs.

**Courtesy:** http://eclecticquill.com/2013/02/26/postgresql-fails-to-start-on-ubuntu-12-10/

Got more info from this [link](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/46C1F311.9070004@pinpointresearch.com):

> But if you are trying a to run an instance of the PostgreSQL server
>   owned by your local user, you need to ensure that the unix socket
>   directory is writable by the user that owns the PostgreSQL server
>   process. Try:
>
> unix_socket_directory='/tmp'

In short:

*We had to do that because we created the `postgres` user manually.*