# If I add a user with no home directory, do they have a password?

Tags: password, security

Referencing the answers to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29359/how-to-add-user-without-home), they give nifty one-liners to create such a user such as:

```
sudo adduser --system --no-create-home --group mightydog
```

After this, can user `mightydog` log on? What is his password?

Comment: Why not try and find out?

Comment: Sometimes my 'try and find out' experiences have ended...poorly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no harm in simply trying it out. On my system (16.04), this resulted in a user with locked password (`*`) and no valid login shell (`/bin/false`), as can be seen from its `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/shadow` entry:

```bsh
# grep mightydog /etc/passwd
mightydog:x:128:138::/home/mightydog:/bin/false

# grep mightydog /etc/shadow
mightydog:*:17610:0:99999:7:::
```

So no, it does not have a password, and it also can not log in by any other means (like SSH keys, or using `sudo -u`) due to the `/bin/false` shell.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll need to investigate how to allow this user to log on via ssh.  I appreciate your adding that bit of info, it saved me a lot of blind alley wandering.

Comment: You just have to specify a login shell like `/bin/bash` and you should be able to log in using `sudo -u` or SSH after setting up key-based authentication.

Comment: Thanks again.  From what I've seen so far, I may also need to set up a minimal home directory to hold the .ssh directory for the user.  But this I *will* be experimenting with.

Comment: FYI this behavior is documented in the `adduser` manpage under `Add a system user`: *"The new system user will have the shell /bin/false (unless overridden  with    the  --shell option), and have logins disabled."*