# permissions of shell script: how to write into /var

Tags: permissions, scripts

I  am writing a backup script. The script is located in `/usr/local/backup-scripts`
The files should be stored to `/var/backup/subdirectory`
I want to run the script using cron job or systemd-timer.

I have no idea how to set the permissions correctly. Of course for testing I can sudo run the script. But what when the cron job or systemd runs the script? Do they (they=cron or systemd) have su-rights?

Unfortunately I am not that familiar with the permission in Linux so I have no idea if I have to chown the script to a special user (maybe sys???) or what the "right" way is. 
Appreciate every help, cheers Stefan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### System user and cron

A simple and secure way would be to create a backup-user as [system user](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29359/how-to-add-a-user-without-home) (no home folder). Then give permissions to the backup-user for the backup location:

```
$ adduser --system --no-create-home backup-user
$ chown -R backup-user /var/backup/subdirectory
```

Also you need to [specify the user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8475694/how-to-specify-in-crontab-by-what-user-to-run-script) in the cron job.

### Backup tool

While writing own backup shell scripts is fun for a little while, sooner or later it becomes hard to mange all the corner cases. So if you get tired of writing shell scripts, checkout [bacula](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/bacula.html.en). It is definitely more work to setup, but it offers more features then self written scripts.

Comment: Good approach. However, depending on the backup _sources_ the `backup-user` might need extra permissions to access all files that ought to be backed up.

Comment: I agree, permission management becomes difficult in a complex environment...

Comment: I run my backup script as `root` so it can access all the sources. But it just depends on _what_ you want to backup.